# C++17 template deduction guide not used for empty parameter set (ver 2)?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, template-argument-deduction

Ran into another weirdness in template deduction guides after [C++17 template deduction guide not used for empty parameter set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45195890/c17-template-deduction-guide-not-used-for-empty-parameter-set) (that bug https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=81486 is still not fixed in GCC trunk unfortunately :( ):

```cpp
#include <utility>

template <class T> struct success
{
  T value;
  constexpr success(T &&v)
      : value(std::move(v))
  {
  }
  constexpr success(const T &v)
      : value(v)
  {
  }
};
template <> struct success<void>
{
};
template <class T> success(T /*unused*/)->success<T>;
success()->success<void>;

template<class T> struct foo
{
    foo(success<void>) {}
};

int main(void)
{
    auto a = success{5};        // works
    auto b = success{};         // works
    auto c = success{"hello"};  // works
    auto d = success(5);        // works
    //auto e = success();         // FAILS on GCC 7.2!
    auto f = success("hello");  // works
    foo<void> g(success());     // FAILS
    static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(a), success<int>>::value, "");
    static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(b), success<void>>::value, "");
    static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(c), success<const char *>>::value, "");
    static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(d), success<int>>::value, "");
    //static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(e), success<void>>::value, "");
    static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(f), success<const char *>>::value, "");
    return 0;
}
```

The surprising line, to me at least, is that `foo<void> g(success());` fails to use the template deduction guides on both clang 6.0 trunk and GCC 7 trunk as you can see at https://godbolt.org/g/7m1Zhk

I find this surprising and not what one would expect. The template guide says that an unadorned `success()` shall be constructed as `success<void>`. That should work just fine with foo's unambiguous constructor accepting a `success<void>`. Instead clang 6.0 trunk reports:

```
34 : <source>:34:17: error: use of class template 'success' requires template arguments; argument deduction not allowed in function return type
    foo<void> g(success());     // FAILS
                ^~~~~~~
3 : <source>:3:27: note: template is declared here
template <class T> struct success
                          ^
```

And GCC 7.3 trunk reports:

```
<source>: In function 'int main()':
34 : <source>:34:25: error: 'auto' parameter not permitted in this context
     foo<void> g(success());     // FAILS
                         ^
```

Can anyone explain what is going on here? Is this a defect in the C++ 17 standard?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you've run into a new form of the Most Vexing Parse.

Remember that the syntactic form of any piece of code is determined before any semantic rules beyond name lookup apply to it.  Now that a *template-name* is syntactically a valid *simple-type-specifier*, it becomes possible to parse

```
foo<void> g(success());
```

as either a definition of an object `g` with initializer or a declaration of a function `g`.  Per the Most Vexing Parse rule, the function parse "wins", so `g` declares a function returning `foo<void>` whose one unnamed parameter is a function with no parameters returning the placeholder class template type `success`.

But then when the semantic checks do kick in, this is not one of the valid uses of a class template placeholder type, so the program is ill-formed.

Note clang will succeed if we make some tweaks to avoid the Most Vexing Parse:

```
foo<void> g2{success()};
struct bar { bar(int, succeed<void>) {} };
bar g3(1, success());
```

However, I think the following double parentheses trick should also work, but it just causes new error messages from clang.  I'm not sure what's up with this one:

```
foo<void> g4((success()));
```

Comment: Ok, thanks for the confirmation as to the cause. It was hard to choose between this and the other answer, both are good, but this one also has a workaround so I figure it better.

Answer (score 2):

This is the most vexing parse.

```
foo<void> g(success());     // FAILS
```

Is the declaration of a function, named `g`, that returns a `foo<void>`, and takes as one [unnamed] parameter of type pointer to nullary function returning `success`.

However, `success` is not a type, it's a template-name, and you cannot use a template-name as a return type of a function, only a full type. Hence, the error.

Comment: template-name, not template-id.

Comment: "However, success is not a type, it's a template-name, and you cannot use a template-name as a return type of a function, only a full type. Hence, the error."

I see the problem now. One workaround for a future standard is if the template type defaults all its template arguments, then that default could be injected into the type space as well as the template space. Yes I agree that this is an awful corner case, but the vexing parse problem prevents me from replacing a set of free functions and shim types with a cleaner template deduction guide system. Which is sad :(